# Audio element not working most of the times

Tags: html, audio

This is my HTML:

```
            <audio
                autoplay
                id="mo"
            >
                <source
                    src="images/wedding.mp3"
                    type="audio/ogg"
                />
                <source
                    src="images/wedding.mp3"
                    type="audio/mpeg"
                />
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
```

It sometimes works. But most of the times it does not work. And I see HTTP Status Code 206 as the response.

I added `preload='auto'` but did not help.

What could be wrong? I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.